# Moving a menu over without messing up spacing

Tags: menu, navigation

Here's the site I'm working on:

http://artificialmarketingsolutions.com/

I'd like to move the nav menu over to the left, so it lines up with the content. But when I change the margins, it squishes the menu all onto the same word.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 317 of your `style.css`, under the `#nav ul` declaration, 
change `padding: 0 0 0 10px;` to `padding: 0`.
Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Kinda, it made it so the menu lined up with the written content, but not the outside of the content box (box with grey border). I added a margin, but that squished the menu together.

Negative value didn't work on the padding.

Comment: Actually, just figured it out. Thanks for the help!